# Can I deploy an https node server to customers' computers without requiring clients to use a security exception in their browser?

Tags: node.js, https

It is possible to deploy a node.js-based https server on our clients' servers, without requiring each of their workstations to add a security exception in the browser to be able to connect to it without a security warning?

Our product prototype creates a self-signed cert on installation, which causes the security warning.  However, given the wide scale of the project, and the fact that we don't own/maintain the hardware where it will be deployed, it seems infeasible to use a "real" cert from a browser-trusted CA for each of the hundreds of customers when the real roll-out occurs.

Some facts about the roll-out:

- We don't necessarily own the hardware or control/maintain the network where the solution would be deployed
- The solution would possibly be deployed to hundred of different servers at hundreds of different sites, so this will not be a one-off project
- Some clients would want this software reachable from the open internet, others only on their intranet
- Clients connect by IP address, not domain name

There could potentially be 2000+ client workstations connecting to these servers at some point, so it's critical that we avoid the need to set an https security exception on each one.

Comment: As far as I know, you need a **domain name** to create a valid certificate. Once created, it does not matter if clients connect by domain name or IP address. Since you client has hundreds of servers, I would be surprised if they don't manage their **local DNS**.

Comment: @RaphaMex It's not that we have a client with hundreds of servers.  It's that we have hundreds of clients who each have 1 server.